# How to locatate an element with Selenium webdriver - market h4 is blank

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to locate an element with Python Selenium Chromedriver from following piece of HTML:

```
<h4 class="destination-sitemap__sublist-title RandomVariable"></h4>
<div class="destination-sitemap__RandomContent">
  <ul class="destination-sitemap_RandomSulist">
    <li class="destination-sitemap_RandomItem">
```

1. The `h4` element have no text - however have unique class.
2. I need to iterate over `li` items

At the moment I can select `h4` element with :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('destination-sitemap__sublist-title RandomVariable')
```

But I was unable to access lower class elements.

Comment: cant see ur html code

Comment: Thanks  Somber for letting me know.

Comment: I see that h4 tag is closed before div so div does not belong to h4
So to iterate li elements you must select div as container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath to identify the elements.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h4[@class='destination-sitemap__sublist-title RandomVariable']/following::div[@class='destination-sitemap__RandomContent']/ul//li")))
for ele in elements:
  print(ele.text)
```

You can induce `WebDriverWait`

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h4[@class='destination-sitemap__sublist-title RandomVariable']/following::div[@class='destination-sitemap__RandomContent']/ul//li")))
for ele in elements:
   print(ele.text)
```

To execute `WebDriverWait` need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Sorry, part of question went missing, when posting question.

Comment: @ArturGorczyński : Try that now?

Comment: Well not exactly  what I was thinking of but will do the job! 
Thanks mate!